# flash button is not loading in IE 7

Tags: php

flash button is not loading in IE 7

this is the button

galtech.org/mygrovephotos/js/uploadify/uploadify.swf

Comment: We need a lot more detail than that? What kind of flash button? Is flash player installed? Any error message?

Comment: it is a flash file upload button using jquery, its not displaying in IE 7

Answer (score 0):

We need more information. Also make sure you have installed [flash player for IE](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/).

Comment: i installed flash player, this is the link for the flash button http://galtech.org/mygrovephotos/js/uploadify/uploadify.swf

Comment: @hwd: This swf file works correctly. I think it is the problem of your installed flash player. Reinstall flash player again and try.